# Communication between two programs signals or shared mem?

Tags: qt, signals, ipc

I need to implement (in Qt) some solution to communicate between two programs running on Linux machine. One program is Worker, and the second is Watchdog. Basically I need Watchdog to periodically check on Worker and in case something wrong (no process,hangup - no answer from Worker) kill Worker (if present) and start it again.
Worker runs as a daemon, so I think starting it from unix /etc/init.d/worker would be appropriate.
I can see two solutions

1. Unix signals - both of them can send and receive Unix SIGUSR1
2. Shared memory

Which one to choose?
With signals both of programs will have to know others pid, probably reading from filesystem /var/run so it looks like a drawback.
With shared memory, all I need is "key" that programs will have hardcoded, so no need to read pids from filesystem. Since Watchdog should start first it can create shared mem segment, and Worker will only attach to it and maybe update its timestamp value??? However, to stop Worker by Watchdog (in case of hungup) Watchdog will still need Worker pid to send him SIGKILL, maybe it can read it from shared mem? Both concepts are new to me.

So what is the proper way to build reliable Watchdog, or am I missing something?

best regards

Marek

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best solution available through Qt:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocalsocket.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocalserver.html

> The QLocalSocket class provides a local socket. On Windows this is a
>   named pipe and on Unix this is a local domain socket.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/ipc-localfortuneserver.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/ipc-localfortuneclient.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's something I haven't considered. I will go for it.